# Has there been evidence of any other gods?

Tags: game-of-thrones

IIRC, the only god we've seen real evidence of in *Game of Thrones* is the Lord of Light. We see it when Beric comes back to life, and well as a couple times with Melisandre (birthing the shadow and bringing Jon Snow back).

But, has there been any evidence of other gods throughout the series, or is the Lord of Light perhaps the *actual* one true god?

Comment: Evidence? No..... the second part of your question is opinion-based I suspect.

Comment: The problem is that we don't actually have specific evidence for the Lord of Light either. We can see Melisandre do quite some magic, but afterall the White Walkers and dragons are inherently magical things, too. So it might be a little fuzzy to argue if that ultimately speaks for her god's power or even existence.

Comment: Same question on the Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE: [Is R'hllor, The Lord of Light, the only “real” god?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11787/31394)

Comment: I think it all very debatable outside of Hodors paradox pushes heavy for predetermined universe, but that's not to say that I think the book narrative more than the TV narrative, really emphasizes the concept of R'hollor vs The Great Other. The TV show has taken WW in a different direction too, where even if they are a representation of "death" and "death" is an entity, they don't come off as malicious, but something apart of the 'greater thing'.  So I think there is "something" in control, but we may never know exactly what or who it is. Martin also said he would not answer "God" questions.

Comment: @DarthLocke "apart" or "a part"?

Comment: There isn't exactly an unambiguous answer anywhere in either the show or the books, and Martin has said that he doesn't plan to make these things explicit in the end anyway. Looking only very superficially, my impression is that the Many-Faced God either literally exists or some corresponding magical force to it exists (hereafter I'll just say "exists" as shorthand), R'hllor and the Great Other exist, the Seven don't exist (or don't directly alter the world), the old gods exist but *only* as a magical force (the force powering weirwood.net, the 3-eyed raven, and the children of the forest).

Comment: (Cont.) The interrelation between some of these isn't obvious to me at all; for example, it isn't clear to me whether the Many-Faced God is really the only god (in which case presumably the adherents of R'hllor somehow gain his blessing without following the teachings of the House of Black & White).

Comment: Proving or disproving the existence of any deity in- or out-universe has eluded mankind for millennia. I don't see it being sorted out in one SE QA ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin: IRL it is true. But there are many fictional universes where we have direct evidence: Marvel and DC comics have gods,...

Comment: @Tetsujin: we find your lack of faith... disturbing.

Comment: There was that crying Wierwood tree in episode one or two, that seemed pretty weird.

Comment: @Taladris Marvel has some very powerful beings. For some cultures, those could very well count as gods. For others, they're merely superhuman (in the mundane sense, e.g. hawk having superhuman long-range vision). Even with magic (in GoT or elsewhere), to have it be proof of gods existing requires you to assume magic flow from gods; that may be what the characters in-universe think, but it's quite a tenuous assertion. And of course, there's always that pesky Clarke's law. Humans have found many real gods (like the mad god of evolution) - and discarded them.

Comment: Is magic enought to prove the existence of god in a fantasy setting? What is a solid proof of god existence?

Comment: @Luaan: fair points. It highlights that to look for proofs of the existence of gods, we need a clear definition of gods. I don't get your reference about the "mad god of evolution".

Comment: @Taladris Well, in the end, a large part of why religions and gods exist (or are thought to exist) is to explain the world around us. For example, the Abrahamic God explains where the amazing variety of animal and plants comes from - something that happened to be far better explained by evolution. Evolution is however entirely inhuman - it is not a god that made "humans in their own image". But that's a long talk :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm going to ignore situations that happened only in the books (i.e. some healers that worship the 7 and seem to perform miracles) and focus on what we've seen on the TV show.

**Mirri Maz Duur:** She used some pretty dark magic on Khal Drogo (and, to some extent, on Daenerys). She worships the Great Shepherd of the Lhazareen. Does that mean the Great Shepherd is real?

**Ironborn:** As mentioned above, the ironborn seem to drown and then come back to life. Does that mean the Drowned God is real?

**Bran:** It seems Bran's magic is linked to the Old Gods (in the books even more so through his Weirwood net). Does that mean the Old Gods are real?

**White Walkers:** Sure, they seem to be the enemies of the "lord of Light", but that's just based on what Melissandre says. We've seen they were created by the Children of the Forest, who are also linked to the Old Gods. So maybe what Melissandre says is just propaganda and the Old Gods are the real thing?

Plus we've seen some weird stuff in Essos (faceless men, Warlocks of Qarth, etc). Each with their own religions.

What we've seen in all these cases (and the ones you mentioned regarding R'hllor) are just proof that *magic* exists, not that a specific *god* exists.

Whether that magic is linked to a god or it's just something that is there (and people use gods as an explanation for the source of the magic) is something we'll never know.

I recall GRRM saying something like "the gods of Westeros are as real as ours", so make of that what you will!

Answer (score 28):

Many-Faced God is worshipped by the Faceless Men who clearly have some form of powerful magic granted to them. It isn't clear exactly how this magic works but we could extrapolate that is comes from the Many-Faced God.

However, the Many-Faced God is a god of many faces, clearly, and one of those faces is R'hllor, the Lord of Light that is worshipped by Melisandre and Thoros. Therefore, it isn't inconceivable that their power also comes from the Lord of Light.

Comment: There's also 'magic' unattributed to any deity - that dragon glass & valyrian steel have 'special powers'.

Comment: That's why I think everything Arya can do is not inconceivable and I think it was definitely curious that Melisandre either triggered something in Arya or passed her along a message, but it's not like Melisandre hasn't mysteriously spoken words of the dead before (Y'Gritte to Jon) and that Faceless Men seem to be able to read minds or also get sensory information from the beyond (JH recited the names on Arya's list)...

Comment: The only other God mentioned is 'Death' and I think the Many-Faced God might even be an attribute of Death...

Comment: "Therefore, it isn't inconceivable that their power also comes from the Lord of Light." uh? you meant the Many-Faced God?

Comment: /agree. The Many-Faced God would be a superset of the Lord of Light

Comment: The drowned God, who is worshiped by the Ironborn, has also been mentioned, being apart of the "Old Gods", but evidence of his existence is sparse and the TV series omits the eternal struggle he has with the Storm God. The Faith of the Seven (7-Faced God, God of the Seven) are heavily worshiped everywhere in Westroros, but the North/Iron Islands. Each persona (Mother, Father, Maiden, Smith, Warrior, Chrone, Starnger) could easily be applied to characters and their arcs, but no other evidence to the God's existence on TV series really exists.

Comment: @DarthLocke "apart" or "a part"?

Comment: MAkes me wonder... being not able to get burned by fire... can this also be connected with any of the deitys?

Comment: How did you made the connection: 1. The god is manyfaced 2. One of the faces is of another god ??? There's no reason to assume this is correct.

Comment: "clearly, and one of those faces is R'hllor". what makes you think that? it's not clear at all

Comment: [The Many-Faced God is Death](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Many-Faced_God), which we learn from the background story with the slaves.  which does not necessarily mean R'hllor is one of those faces.

Answer (score 5):

The Lord of Light and the Many Face god obvious made themselves known because we see things a happen that humans can't produce on their own.

I would argue, in the show the Drowned god has also proved its existence although it was very subtle. When Euron Greyjoy goes through his King ceremony he actually drowns and is brought back, "what is dead may never die".  I've watched the scene a couple times and it doesn't look like they're playing around, he really drowns and is brought back by the Drowned god. And everyone there was normal with it because thats what they were expecting.

If the Drowned god is real and one of the old gods maybe theres enough evidence to at lease say the other ones used to exist. Just look what Bran can do, and we all know he's on team old gods because of his connection to the Weirwood tree.

Tbh, i'd like to think the new gods are fake. Hope you like my answer, I think the old gods are real/mostly retired.

Comment: Who says that humans can't do those things on their own? Magic exists, but there's no proof that magic is provided by any gods.

Comment: I'm not saying that humans doing magic on their own isn't possible, being a warg or the people at the house of the undying are good examples. But I'm talking about people relying on gods to do their magic for their god's purpose. If Euron Greyjoy could just choose to not die by drowning wouldn't we see him use that kind of power more often? Its because he can't do it and the Drowned god brought him back. I don't think I need to list examples for the lord of light and many face god, everything magical in their story has been to support their godly wants.

Comment: Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic. Any sufficiently advanced magic is indistinguishable from a god.

Comment: You seem to be mixing normal medieval mindset with the way people think in GoT show. There is a strong sense of science in GoT, although it may not be popular and we don't see it very often. A good example is Qyburn and how he fixed up the mountain. He's doesn't consider himself a wizard or magical. And Sir Jorah didn't think it was magic that cured his greyscale at the Citadel. He knew it was Sam's research in medical practice/science.

Comment: @Jeffyx: More info: In the books, they're quite clear that it's very common for people to drown and die during the drowning ceremony, but there's on particularly holy priest who's done _tons_ of these, and has never lost a single person.

Comment: @Jeffyx Hmm, interesting take on the Drowned god. I never thought about their god bringing them back, but that if they were worthy of being king then they would come back on their own. Like, their spirit is strong enough to endure drowning and almost dying.

Comment: @Jeffyx: Mind you, wasn't Qyburn also the one who noted that their "scientific" wildfire just happened to be getting easier to make (at almost the exact same time Dany's dragons hatched). Just because they think it's science doesn't mean it isn't magically powered.

Comment: In the books the drownings are the Iron Islands extremely metal form of a baptism. They DO drown the person, but the priests are extremely well practiced at mouth-to-mouth resuscitation. Victarion Greyjoy (who drowns Euron) has never lost one. Other priests do sometimes lose people during drownings, but it’s still common for priests to wander the islands inviting the faithful to reinforce their faith by being drowned. It’s nothing to do with magic, and all to do with the skill of the priest

Comment: Besides this being a movie & tv form I think its a good idea to ignore the books when discussing the show. The writers really only steal what they want from the books. Books != Show. @s3raph86 "priests are extremely well practiced at mouth-to-mouth resuscitation" I didn't see any mouth to mouth in the show. If you think the show's targeted audience are the people who read the books I'd re-watch seasons 6-8.